# Document ready event of another location opened using window.location in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using below code to open a link on button click. The link is pointing to a Controller method responsible for downloading some Excel file.

```
        // Button to download table data
        $("#btnDownloadCIRResults").click(function (e) {
            var All_Recs = $("#cbShowAllRecords").prop("checked") ? "YES" : "NO";

            DisplayStatusMessageWind("Downloading report, please wait...", MessageType.Info, true, false);

            // DownloadCIRemediationTable(string AllRecords)
            window.location = '/AskNow/DownloadCIRemediationTable?AllRecords=' + All_Recs;

            DisplayStatusMessageWind("Report downloaded successfully.", MessageType.Success, false, true, 1000);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

The Controller method queries a DB table, converts it to an Excel workbook and returns a file as download result. All is working fine and as expected, except, since this is a time consuming process, I just want to improve on user experience and update this code to show some wait message while the file is being downloaded.

The `DisplayStatusMessageWind()` method shows a wait message. However, it doesn't know or care about the load complete event of the `window.location = '/AskNow/DownloadCIRemediationTable?AllRecords=' + All_Recs;` code.

How can I make the completion message appear only after the file download is completed:

`DisplayStatusMessageWind("Report downloaded successfully.", MessageType.Success, false, true, 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

By assigning a new location with `window.location = "<NEWURL>";` you're requesting asynchronously to replace the current page. What will happen, is that the next line is immediately executed (`DisplayStatusMessage()`). When all events are handled, the page will finally be replaced. The new page (URL) will load and you'll have no control whatsoever about how or what will happen next.

What you should do is use `window.open("<NEWURL>", '_blank')` [MOZ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and then on the new page send a signal via `localStorage`, which can be read and written by all pages of the same domain. These are some hints, to write the actual code is your job.

On this page, in `on("click")` event:

```js
// local scope
var ukey;

// polling function
function waitOtherIsReady()
{
  if (localStorage.getItem(ukey) === true)
  {
    // other page experienced ready event
    localStorage.removeItem(ukey); // clean-up

    // TODO: do your stuff

  } else {
    setTimeout(waitOtherIsReady, 500);
  }
}

// create unique key and deposit it in localStorage
ukey = "report_" + Math.random().toString(16);
localStorage.setItem(ukey, false);

// pass key to other page
window.open("URL?ukey=" + ukey, "_blank");

// start polling until flag is flipped to true
setTimeout(waitOtherIsReady, 500);
```

On the other page:

```js
$(() => {
  // get ukey from URL
  var ukey = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("ukey");

  // page is now ready, flip flag to signal ready event
  localStorage.setItem(ukey, true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, the target ink is not a page. It is pointing to a Controller method which returns an Excel file. When user clicks on the button it just stays on the same page and an Excel file gets downloaded without changing the current page/URL

Comment: I understand. I'm not aware of any events that you could leverage. This does not mean there aren't any. I'm just saying I never had to use them and can't help you any further. Wait and see if someone else can help. Otherwise, you should handle this server-side. The server can detect when a send has been handled correctly or terminated prematurely. The page can then poll the server with AJAX in a similar manner as shown above. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will wait for more inputs before I an give a try for using `$.ajax()` and it's `success: function() { }`